# Having trouble with chaining method calls in Java

Tags: java, methods, method-chaining

I am working on an assignment that requires me to call a `findInventoryItem` method to search for an item by part number, and then use the `getQuantity` method in another class to find the quantity of said item. I am having trouble putting this concept of chaining together. Since the `findInventoryItem` method's data type is an object, how do I get the quantity of the object to be returned as an integer?

This is what I have so far, intending on adding a check for a non zero quantity in an if loop.

```
    public int numberInInventory(int partNumber)
{
    findInventoryItem(partNumber).getQuantity();



}
```

Here is the getQuantity in the other class.

```
public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}
```

Here is the findInventoryItem method.

```
public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(int searchPartNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < items.size()){
        InventoryItem inventoryItem = items.get(index);
        int fetchedPartNumber = inventoryItem.getPartNumber();
        if(fetchedPartNumber == searchPartNumber){
            return inventoryItem; 
        }
        else{
            index++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you getting an error? If so, please post the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have just not understood how expressions work.

> Since the findInventoryItem method's data type is an object, how do I get the quantity of the object to be returned as an integer?

findInventoryItem does return an object, but we then call `getQuantity()` on that object, which (presumably) returns an integer. As a result, the expression you have evaluates to an int.

The code you have at the moment is really just a shorthand for:

```
WhateverThatObjectClassIs item = findInventoryItem(partNumber);
item.getQuantity();
```

Now (hopefully) you can see that all you need to do is assign the result of your expression to a variable:

```
int quantity = findInventoryItem(partNumber).getQuantity();
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks so much. Tested and confirmed. I knew the solution was a simple one, but I just couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I can haz shiny green tick?

Comment: You'll get a null pointer exception if the findInventoryItem method returns a null.

Comment: Clearly, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Also, advocating putting a null check around every function call that returns an object would be very harmful.